# Bag of words causing google colab to crash?

Tags: scikit-learn, countvectorizer

**problem**

I am using bag of words for extracting features from text but when i used a model to predict the result, it is causing runtime error

**feature extraction code**

```
bag_of_words = CountVectorizer()

#extracting features from bag of words
x_train_bg = bag_of_words.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test_bg = bag_of_words.transform(x_test)
```

**model prediction**

```
model = GaussianNB()
model.fit(x_train_bg.toarray(), y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(x_test_bg.toarray())
```

I know that problem is due to excessive memory usage so  does that mean that i cannot use bag of words or tfidf for feature extraction , if it can be used then what's  the change that needs to be implemented

Comment: What is the error?